# How Do I Assert Against a Class Attribute?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

```
<mat-checkbox _ngcontent-qei-c197="" id="sacSignoffChkbox" class="mat-checkbox mat-accent mat-checkbox-disabled ng-untouched ng-pristine">
```

I have the checkbox above and it is displaying as disabled on the website because of the `mat-checkbox-disabled` class. I want to assert that that part of the class is not there before I try to click on it. However, my test is passing even when I try to click on it.

I have tried
`bool checkBoxEnabled = auditPage.SACReviewCheckbox.Enabled; Assert.IsTrue(checkBoxEnabled, "The SAC Review Checkbox is not enabled");`

I have also tried

```
var checkBoxEnabled = auditPage.SACReviewCheckbox.GetProperty("mat-checkbox-disabled"); Assert.IsNull(checkBoxEnabled);
```

Both of those asserts pass and even the click action is passing as well even though the box is not getting checked.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to make this work, I did a `FindElements` on the class name of `mat-checkbox-disabled`. This produces a list. I then asserted that the list was empty. This made my test fail which is what I was looking for since the user is supposed to be able to check the checkbox but currently cannot.

```
List<IWebElement> checkBoxEnabled = new List<IWebElement>(LufasWebManager.Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("mat-checkbox-disabled")));
Assert.IsEmpty(checkBoxEnabled, "The SAC Review Checkbox is not enabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage You to find that element by id anyway, and then check if it contains class:

```
Assert.False(auditPage.SACReviewCheckbox.GetAttribute("class").Split(" ").ToList().Contains("mat-checkbox-disabled"))
```

Your approach should be avoided as other elements probably may also contain that "mat-checkbox-disabled" class (other checkboxes in example). In general if You have id on some element always find it by that id as it should be unique (having two same ids on two elements is an error).